# can't get location in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

It gives me this error (double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference)

I tried many many different solutions but all of the same, I know that fusedLocationClient.lastLocation it just gives the last location from other apps, but I don't want that, I want to get the current location without it because it gives null? so how to fix this and get current Location???

```
import android.Manifest
import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.LocationManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.firebase.geofire.GeoFire
import com.firebase.geofire.GeoLocation
import com.firebase.geofire.GeoQueryEventListener
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.moapp.guardaroundd.R
import com.moapp.guardaroundd.databinding.FragmentMapBinding
import com.moapp.guardaroundd.utils.Constants.DEFAULT_ZOOM
import com.moapp.guardaroundd.utils.Constants.LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE
import com.moapp.guardaroundd.utils.createAlertEnableLocation


class MapFragment : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback {

   private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
   private lateinit var binding: FragmentMapBinding
   private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
   private var mLocationPermissionsGranted = false


   override fun onCreateView(
       inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
       savedInstanceState: Bundle?
   ): View {
       // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       binding = FragmentMapBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

       val mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
       mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

       fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireActivity())


       return binding.root
   }

   override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
       mMap = googleMap

       getLocationPermission()

   }

   private fun isLocationEnabled(): Boolean {
       val locationManager =
           activity?.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager?
       return locationManager!!.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) || locationManager.isProviderEnabled(
           LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER
       )
   }

   private fun moveCamera(latLng: LatLng) {
       mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, DEFAULT_ZOOM))
   }

      private fun getLocation() {

       if (isLocationEnabled()) {
           try {
               fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener {
                   moveCamera(LatLng(it.latitude, it.longitude))
                   mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true
               }
           } catch (ex: SecurityException) {

           }
       } else {
           //Custom alert
           createAlertEnableLocation(requireContext())
       }

   }

   private fun getLocationPermission() {
       if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
               requireContext(),
               Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
           )
           == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
       ) {
           mLocationPermissionsGranted = true
           getLocation()

       } else {
           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
               requireActivity(), arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
               LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE
           )
       }
   }


   override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
       requestCode: Int,
       permissions: Array<String>,
       grantResults: IntArray
   ) {
       mLocationPermissionsGranted = false
       when (requestCode) {
           LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE -> {

               // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
               if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() &&
                   grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
               ) {
                   mLocationPermissionsGranted = true
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to avoid the `null location` would be to launch the ***Google Maps App*** and press my location button. You then go back to your app and `fusedLocationClient.lastLocation` will this time give you non-null device last location.

Since you clearly don't prefer this then you need to work with [Location Updates](https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates).

For that I would tweak you `getLocation()` code a little bit.

```
private fun getLocation() {
        // last known location from fusedLocationProviderClient returned as a task
        fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation
                //check if the last location is null
            .addOnSuccessListener { lastLoc ->
                if (lastLoc != null) {

                    // initialize lastKnownLocation from fusedLocationProviderClient
                    lastKnownLocation = lastLoc
                    moveCamera(LatLng(lastLoc.latitude, lastLoc.longitude))
                } else {
                    //if null trigger location update to get location
                    fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(
                        locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper()
                    )
                }
                // in case of error Toast the error in a short Toast message
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {

                Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "${it.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
    }
```

I would also need to bring in the `LocationRequest` and `Location Callback` into the play.

```
class MapFragment : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback { .......

    // LOCATION COMPONENTS
    private lateinit var lastKnownLocation: Location
    private lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient

    private val locationRequest =
        LocationRequest().apply {
            priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
            interval = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10)
            fastestInterval = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1)
        }


    private val locationCallback =
        object : LocationCallback() {

            override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult?) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult)

                if (locationResult != null) {

                    lastKnownLocation = locationResult.lastLocation
                      //call the above getLocation() again to move camera
                   getLocation()
                }
            }
        }
```

So whenever the last known location from the fusedClient is null, an update is triggered and the Camera position is moved.